# public friend function in C++?

Tags: c++, friend

I saw some code in C++ and have a question about it:

```
  class CRectangle {
        int width, height;
      public:
        friend CRectangle duplicate (CRectangle);
    };
```

The variables `width` and `height` are private, and the method `duplicate()` is public. The keyword `friend` is for accessing the private and protected functions outside of a `CRectangle` object, but `duplicate()` is already public.  If it can be accessed from the outside, why do we need "friend"?

Does this mean that, although we directly call a public method like `duplicate()` outside of the class, if the method accesses some private variable, it is also not allowed and we have to declare it as "friend?"

This is the implementation of the `duplicate()` function; I just want to make the question clear:

```
CRectangle duplicate (CRectangle rectparam)
{
  CRectangle rectres;
  rectres.width = rectparam.width*2;
  rectres.height = rectparam.height*2;
  return (rectres);
}
```

Comment: What sort of function is duplicate?  If it's part of the CRectangle class, lose the `friend`.  If it isn't, that gives it the ability to access and change private members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you remove `friend`, this function will become a method - a `function`, that is declared inside the class and is a `public method` (as there's `public:` )

If you put `friend` in front of `duplicate`, this means that you *declare* a function, that is not a member of the class, that takes one argument - `CRectangle` and that have access to `private`/`protected` members of the class.

The second case requires definition for `CRectangle duplicate( CRectangle )`

Both cases are different.

---

EDIT:
For `friend`, the access specifier doesn't matter.

By "The second case requires definition for `CRectangle duplicate( CRectangle )`", I mean, that the first case requires definition, too, but it is

```
//         vvvvvvvvvvvv
CRectangle CRectangle::duplicate( CRectangle )
```

Comment: In C++, the correct terminology is "member function", not "method".

Answer (score 6):

The Golden Rule is:

***Friend functions can be declared under any Access Specifier, the access specifier rules do not apply to friend functions.***

In your example,

```
friend CRectangle duplicate (CRectangle);
```

is declared as friend function under `public` access specifier but it would still behave exactly the same manner even if declared under a `private` access specifier.

You are mistaking the function to be as a member function and hence the question. It is ***NOT***.The function is returning a object of the type `CRectangle` and is friend of the same class `CRectangle`.

The function `CRectangle duplicate (CRectangle)` can access all the `private & protected` members of the class `CRectangle` because it is declared `friend of the class` not because it is declared under the public access specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: `duplicate` is not a member of `CRectangle`. You are declaring `duplicate` as a free function, which function is a friend of `CRectangle`.

```
class C {
public:
    friend void F(); // declares non-member F
    void F(); // declares member F
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a good question, the syntax is a little confusing.

The syntax does not mean that `duplicate` is a member function of the class `CRectangle`.  Rather it means that the function (regular function) `duplcate` has access to the private details of `CRectangle`.  Its indicating that "permission is granted to the duplicate function".

The function `duplicate` may <del>still needs to</del> be declared and defined as any other regular function (outside the `CRectangle` class).  I prefer to do this as a reminder that its a regular free function

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: in which case, it can only be found by ADL.  Which probably isn't a problem here, but is the sort of thing which can confuse beginners.